# Is std::async broken in gcc 4.7 on linux?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++11, pthreads, gcc4.7

I'm testing `std::async` in isolation before using it in real code, to verify that it works correctly on my platform (which is ubuntu 12.10 64-bit).

It works (somewhat rarely) and usually just hangs. If it works for you, don't jump to conclusions. Try a few more times, it will probably hang.

If I remove the pthread_mutex test, it doesn't hang. This is the smallest code I can get to reproduce the hang. Is there some reason that you can't mix C pthread code with c++ async code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
std::string format_ns(T &&value)
{
    std::stringstream s;
    if (std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
        s << std::setprecision(3);

    if (value >= 1000000000)
        s << value / 1000000000 << "s";
    else if (value >= 1000000)
        s << value / 1000000 << "ms";
    else if (value >= 1000)
        s << value / 1000 << "us";
    else
        s << value  << "ns";
    return s.str();
}

template<typename F>
void test(const std::string &msg, int iter, F &&lambda)
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;
    auto st = clock.now();

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < iter; ++i)
        lambda();
    auto en = clock.now();
    std::chrono::nanoseconds dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<
        std::chrono::nanoseconds>(en-st);

    std::cout << msg << format_ns(dur.count() / i) << std::endl;
}

int test_pthread_mutex()
{
    pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    test("pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock: ", 1000000000,
    [&]()
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    });

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);

    return 0;
}

int test_async()
{
    test("async: ", 100,
    [&]()
    {
        auto asy = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){});
        asy.get();
    });

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    test_pthread_mutex();
    test_async();
}
```

Here is the build command line:

```
g++ -Wextra -Wall  --std=c++11 -pthread mutexperf/main.cpp
```

There are no build output messages.

Here is the output of g++ -v

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
```

Comment: I have the same compiler and setup as you. I'm not able to reproduce. Code look fine.

Comment: @johan I thought that it might not reproduce. I'll try it on some other machines and see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it on a few different computers and found that it indeed worked fine like @johan commented. I investigated the machine I was using and found evidence that the hard drive is beginning to fail. It has some bad sectors and also saw `dmesg` report several "hard resets" of the HDD after an unusual 4 second freeze. Odd, I hadn't seen any issues before I posted the question. It's probably some subtle/intermittent corruption when compiling/linking or perhaps when loading the executable.

```
[44242.380936] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x800000 action 0x6 frozen
[44242.380942] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[44242.380946] ata3: SError: { LinkSeq }
[44242.380950] sr 2:0:0:0: CDB: 
[44242.380952] Get event status notification: 4a 01 00 00 10 00 00 00 08 00
[44242.380965] ata3.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0 pio 16392 in
[44242.380965]          res 50/00:03:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[44242.380968] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[44242.380974] ata3: hard resetting link
[44242.700025] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[44242.704849] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
[44242.720055] ata3: EH complete
[44970.117542] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x800100 action 0x6 frozen
[44970.117547] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[44970.117551] ata3: SError: { UnrecovData LinkSeq }
[44970.117555] sr 2:0:0:0: CDB: 
[44970.117557] Get event status notification: 4a 01 00 00 10 00 00 00 08 00
[44970.117570] ata3.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0 pio 16392 in
[44970.117570]          res 50/00:03:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[44970.117573] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[44970.117579] ata3: hard resetting link
[44970.436662] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[44970.443159] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
[44970.456639] ata3: EH complete
```

Thanks to anyone who spent time looking at my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to copy the mutex rather than pass by reference in lambda?

```
int test_pthread_mutex()
{
    pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    test("pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock: ", 1000000000,
    [=]()
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    });

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);

    return 0;
}
```